# How to use Stored Procedure Select a value using while

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL table name category.here is the structure.

```
slno      Category            Uppercategory

1           Mouse              Computer

2          Computer            Electronics

3          Electronics           END

4           END                    -
```

Here the mouse in the uppercategory Computer and then the Computer in the uppercategory Electronics.and the Electronics is the last uppercategory because the Electronics having the uppercategory ENd.I need to get the last category(Electronics)which the uppercatergory is END.
I tried some code but not get the result.here is my code.

```
USE [Database1]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[kt_category]
       @Dcat AS NVARCHAR(250)
AS
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (cater NVARCHAR(255))

BEGIN 

INSERT INTO @tmp 
SELECT UPPERCATEGORY FROM CATEGORY where CATEGORY=@Dcat

while( SELECT UPPERCATEGORY FROM CATEGORY )= 'END'
RETURN
END
```

Comment: Why 'HOVED' instead of 'END' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a recursive query to achieve this.

```
;WITH R
     AS (SELECT *,
                1 AS Level
         FROM   CATEGORY
         WHERE  Category = @Dcat
         UNION ALL
         SELECT C.*,
                R.Level + 1
         FROM   CATEGORY C
                JOIN R
                  ON R.Uppercategory = C.Category)
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   R
ORDER  BY Level DESC
```

You could also use

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   R
WHERE Uppercategory  = 'End'
ORDER  BY Level
```

as the final query. This has closer semantics to the code in your question.

Comment: I tried this query in my table but I get the answer like
Category       Uppercategory
END              

I need Before this step.need the category when uppercategory is END

Comment: @user2318361 - So specifically what do you need returned from your example data? Computer?

Comment: NO I need Electronics..Just now I edited my example you can see.

Comment: @user2318361 - That is what my query returns. Just use the `CATEGORY` column from the final `SELECT`. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4dd6f/2) (Edit - Oh I see you've changed the example data. In that case use the second version in my answer http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/564ed/1 )

Comment: Yes.Nice Sir.It is Working and got my answer which what I need the same.Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: I have another doubt Can I ask?

Comment: @Arun - Yes though if it is significantly different you might want to ask it as a new question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30752/discussion-between-arun-and-martin-smith)